# No update in the mongoose-cache after change in the collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, caching, mongoose

I have a MEAN stack based application and recently, I was trying to implement some caching mechanism for caching the query results. I implemented [mongoose-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-cache).

mongoose-cache configuration

```
require('mongoose-cache').install(mongoose, {max: 150, maxAge:1000*60*10});
```

I have two document in sample collection say

```
{name:'dale', dep:2},
{name:'john', dep:4}
```

I run a query with mongoose-cache enabled and the **maxAge is say 10 minutes**.

```
sample.find().cache().exec(function (err, doc) {
        // returns 2 document
    });
```

Next, I inserted one more document say 
 `{name:'rasig', dep:4}` and execute the same query

```
sample.find().cache().exec(function (err, doc) {
        // returns 2 document instead of 3
    });
```

I executed the same query twice within 10 minutes, though there was a change in the collection, I got the previous result. Is there any way to drop the cached result once there is a change in the collection. If not, can you suggest something else to implement the same.

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of a new Mongoose module called [Monc](https://github.com/vorillaz/monc)

Using Monc is quite easy to clean up or purge the whole cache or even the the associated Query objects simple by using:

```
sample.find().clean().cache().exec(function (err, doc) {});
```